# Which media players available in the Ubuntu repositories uses GStreamer, GTK+ and were written in Python?

Tags: python, gtk3, gstreamer, official-repositories, python3

I'm planning to write a media player for Ubuntu to present in fair in the place I study. And I'd like to use GStreamer and GTK+ with Python, but I could not find a good documentation about the GStreamer binding on Python and I'd like to see some code examples. So I'd like to request (please) a list with some media players available in the Ubuntu repositories uses GStreamer, GTK+ and were written in Python? If possible in Python 3, but this may be asking too much.

Note: I tried to look for some on Launchpad but is pretty hard to find something in general there because there is no filters for searching something like media players.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Exaile** is an excellent media player in the standard repositories (the *exaile* package) written in Python and GTK+ which uses GStreamer. The code is hosted on launchpad: https://launchpad.net/exaile Not GTK+ 3 or Python 3 yet but some work was started: https://bugs.launchpad.net/exaile/+bug/846379

**Quod Libet** is another option in the *quodlibet* package (found thanks to Timo's tip below), and the code is available here: https://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/ The 3.0 version (not in the repositories yet) appears to be ported to use GObject Introspection, but still uses Python 2 as well.

Comment: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/apps/ also mentions `Listen` and `Quod Libet`.